# Find an alternative to split when processing a lot of data

Tags: javascript, object

I am mapping through the object in order to return an array of object. However I want to modify the "model-1111" from a string to an integer. This method works with a split, however I would like to find an alternative to split, because split will return an array, which is not the best when processing a lot of data.

```js
const data = { "model-10389": 164703, "model-10388": 164704, "model-10387": 164705 };

const output = Object.entries(data).map(([key, id]) => ({
  modelId: +key.split("-").pop(),
  id
}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You could take a substring `+s.substring(s.indexOf('-') + 1);`

Comment: do you have always the same prefix?

Comment: thank you so much you have helpe me a lot

Comment: I'm glad my comment/answer helped. see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and accept my answer if it solved your issue. This makes the question a valid duplicate target and helps future askers.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) the string from the [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) the `'-'`

```js
const data = { "model-10389": 164703, "model-10388": 164704, "model-10387": 164705 };

const output = Object.entries(data).map(([key, id]) => ({
  modelId: +key.slice(key.indexOf("-") + 1),
  id
}));

console.log(output);
```

Or using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to find the trailing digits (`\d+$`)

```js
const data = { "model-10389": 164703, "model-10388": 164704, "model-10387": 164705 };

const output = Object.entries(data).map(([key, id]) => ({
  modelId: +key.match(/\d+$/),
  id
}));

console.log(output);
```

Or, as I believe Nina Scholz was hinting at in the comments, you could simply [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the prefix with an empty string.

```js
const data = { "model-10389": 164703, "model-10388": 164704, "model-10387": 164705 };

const output = Object.entries(data).map(([key, id]) => ({
  modelId: +key.replace('model-', ''),
  id
}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the split activities by supplying the second (optional) argument.

```js
const data = {"model-10389-extra": 164703,  "model-10388": 164704,  "model-10387": 164705};

  const output = Object.entries(data).map(([key, id]) => ({
  modelId: +key.split("-",2)[1],
  id
  }));

 console.log(output);
```